# How to get the right try_files $uri directive working with _GET parameters in nginx

Tags: php, nginx, get

I just migrated a site from apache to nginx, and am very pleased so far.  However, the server doesn't seem to recognize a $_GET parameter.

I've read that the answer is to change the try_files directive to:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

But this isn't working for me.  I suspect it's because the query string I'm using is a few directories in, with the url something like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/thedirectory/thefile?sortby=director
```

I just can't tweak the try_files directive to work in that instance, and the documentation seems sparse or obsolete.

Any ideas?  If I don't get this resolved, I'm going to have to go back to Apache.

Comment: The answer seems to be in my fastcgi_params.  I added this, which worked for a few minutes before crashing my server.  Location config:

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING    $query_string;
    }

Comment: You don't `include fastcgi_params` in your php block ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you got that answer from,but in the context of your problem I don't see the relevance. Let's first get something clarified:

1. Try_files looks to match the URI with a physical location on disk and allows you to control the fallback action.
2. The default fallback is to throw a 404.
3. $query_string is not relevant to the matching process. It is used for try_files constructs where something has to be added to the query string.

There are three possible causes and remedies for your problem:

1. The uri matches a real file, but without the file extension, which causes the php processing location to not get triggered. In this case your statement should be:

   try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php;
2. This is a virtual location and the router is in index.php, like it it's with many applications, like WordPress and Magento.
   In this case the try_files should be:

   try_files $uri $uri/ @appname;

Without more context providing a location block for @appname is not possible.

1. You are not including relevant fastcgi_param directives. In this case your try_files is noise. Fix the actual problem first, by including the provided example fastcgi_param, as mentioned in the comments.